# How to get code to run in background thread in Android in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get code to run in a background thread in Kotlin on Android. The reason I want to do this is because the UI is not displaying and my searching has shown that this is because the work I was doing in the main thread was stopping the UI from rendering. Here is the code I have so far:

```
package com.example.senddynamicsms

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.util.Log
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.concurrent.Executor
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import kotlin.random.Random
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var counter = 0
    val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val executorService: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)


    private fun getPermission () {
        val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
            ) {
                Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it")
                val permissions = arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }
    }
    fun makeSMSSender () {
        val executor: Executor
        executor.execute() {
            val ret = loop()
        }
    }
    private fun loop(){
        while (true) {
            if (counter < 100) {
                sendDynamicSMS()
            } else {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    private fun sendDynamicSMS () {
        val internationalCode = "+44"
        val mobileNetworkCode = "77"
        val i1 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n1 = i1.toString()
        val i2 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n2 = i2.toString()
        val i3 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n3 = i3.toString()
        val i4 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n4 = i4.toString()
        val i5 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n5 = i5.toString()
        val i6 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n6 = i6.toString()
        val i7 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n7 = i7.toString()
        val i8 = Random.nextInt(0, 9)
        val n8 = i8.toString()
        val number = "$internationalCode$mobileNetworkCode$n1$n2$n3$n4$n5$n6$n7$n8"
        Log.d("", "Trying to send to $number")
        try {
            SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, "https://wottot.com/7NoahideLaws.html", null, null)
            Log.d("", "Message sent")
            counter++
            val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
            Log.d("", "Sent $counter messages in ${(end - begin)/1000} seconds")
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            Log.d("", "Message not sent")
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        getPermission()
        makeSMSSender()
        exitProcess(-1)
    }
}
```

I get the following error at build time

```
Variable 'executor' must be initialized
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: In `makeSMSSender()`, you have not assigned a value to `executor`. Either get rid of that variable or assign a value to it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm having trouble assigning a value to executor. Could you give an example one liner that would do the job?

Comment: I do not even know why you have that variable. You have an `Executor` implementation in `executorService`, and you do not seem to actually use that anywhere. So, perhaps you should remove `executor` and use your existing `executorService`.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK. I did that. The program builds and runs. But the app still doesn't display the UI nor do I get any output in the logcat for the code that should be running in a background thread.

Comment: When the activity is started, `onResume()` will run and `exitProcess` will close the application.  Try removing the call to `exitProcess(-1)`.